# How to show words saved in other language like Urdu, Spanish etc (in DB) using JAVA.

Tags: java, utf-8, html-entities

I am saving text in other language like Urdu, Punjabi, Spanish etc in DB from HTML form. It gets saved in DB and I am able to display same text in same language via PHP on UI (HTML page). Now I want to do same thing in JAVA. In PHP I am using `html_entity_decode()`. How can I do same in JAVA.

Thanks in advance for your help. Please let me know if my question is not clear to you.

Comment: you can use google-api-translate-java for translation

Comment: I don't want to translate, I want to display the exact text that is entered by user in text box, either in English or any other language.

Comment: @Tiya: it seems to me that your question is not about how to display i18n views but how to store in a db data filled by a user and then to display them in the exact same way that they were entered.

Comment: Yes, but I am able to store it in DB, the only part left is to display.

Comment: The issue here is to enforce the use of the same charset in the db and in the html pages where the data are displayed. As soon as there aren't the same, you need an explicit charset conversion. PHP html_entity_decode doesn't do it: it role is to escape the html entities.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do it with Java is through property files:

- one file per language
- each file is filled with a list of pairs key/message
- the files are managed with an instance of ResourceBundle class

See for ex. [Backing a ResourceBundle with Properties Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html)

About using it in html pages, it depends how you generate them.

UPDATE

About storing data filled by a user in any language.

It is strongly recommended to encode the data with a unique charset, usually UTF-8, all along the way, i.e.:

- from the html form where the user enters data
- to the html displaying them
- through the db used to store them.

For html, the charset must be set up in all the pages.

For db, check what is the default charset used, and if needed changed it (if it's possible!)

If at any step of the process a change of charset is required, then explicit conversion will be needed.

Most of the time, Java deals with encoding without requiring to explicit any charset. But it not always true, like e.g. with copy from String to byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to explain the necessary steps to use Arabic language font in Android app development.You can customize this according to your requirement.  Same procedure is applicable to other languages including Persian or urdu.
[Follow this link for complete example](http://www.technocrazed.com/using-arabic-urdu-persian-and-other-languages-fonts-in-android-app-development)

Another helpful API would be JAVA Internationalization.[Check Its documentation for further help](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/overview.html)

Comment: We don't know in which language user is going to enter text. Also I need to get text from DB and then display on JSP page or HTML page.

Comment: In that case you will have to include font files for all the possible languages.

Comment: But that is not feasible solution, don't we have any function or anything else like we have in PHP html_entity_decode(). Using this function we can show the exact text entered by user. Moreover, we can't determine in which language user has entered the text, which font file we need to use.

Comment: It seems to me there are two different issues here. About font able to display any language, any unicode one will do the job as e.g. the Google noto fonts https://www.google.com/get/noto/. About html_entity_decode: is it to escape html entities? If so then it's not related to i18n issue.